# UTF-8 characters not displaying correctly when executing selenium code from jenkins

Tags: selenium, utf-8

I have a language text file where some UTF-8 characters are there to validate. I set the encoding format to UTF-8 for that file and also in the POM file configured the UTF-8 encoding format.

But when we executed the script from Jenkins (we kept our selenium solution in the server (TFS) and executing the script in selenium grid from different nodes (VMs)) those characters are not displayed correctly when we read the text from UI using **driver.gettext** property. [Term�kadatok]
it's displayed some question marks.

can you please help me on this. if i have to do something in Node VMs or in jenkins.

thanks
Nihar Ranjan Arisal

Comment: Can you take a screenshot of your page and check if the symbol is correctly rendered at the page?

Comment: yes, the symbol correctly displayed in the screenshot.